# Disable iAd for an existing App without updating it

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

I'm trying to disable iAd for an existing app.
The main reason is that I don't want to receive any other payment for that specific app.
I know that:

- I can unpublish the app

or, better,

- I can send an updated binary with no iAd support

but both this cases doesn't cover all the situations: what if an user doesn't update the app? He will continue to receive ads and potentially trigger a payment.
Obviously I can remove my payment informations, but it's not what I want now (I want to continue to receive payments for other apps).
Any suggestion?